# XML sum of values as a new value

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, count, sum

I have the following XML:

```
<team>
   <name>Sanha</name>
   <players>
      <player>
         <name>Alberto Carreiras</name>
         <skill>7</skill>
      </player>
      <player>
         <name>Uông Bửu Đích</name>
         <skill>8</skill>
      </player>
      ...
   </players>
   <sum>0</sum>
</team>

<team>
...
</team>
```

Is there a simple and direct way to calculate the sum of `skill` and insert it to a tag? To achieve the following result:

```
<team>
   <name>Sanha</name>
   <players>
      <player>... </player>
      <player>...</player>
      ...
   </players>
   <sum>15</sum>
</team>
```

I can approach with XPath to get the sum:

```
sum(/team/name["Sanha"]/following-sibling::players/player/skill)
```

Let's assume I have a working XSD file describing the values. All letters are `xsd:string` and all numbers are `xsd:float`. All with no restrictions.

However I have no idea how to parse this value to `sum` tag.

Comment: XPath does allow you to select nodes in an input document and to compute values based on the input, so your XPath expression would compute a sum, yes. But XPath does not allow you to create a new document or manipulate the existing one, to add a `sum` element you need XSLT or XQuery or DOM with XPath support.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you tell me how to do it with XSLT? I've seen it's like a combination of XML and HTML. How to put a calculation to a tag?

Comment: Well, why is the sum of `7` and `8` `7.5`? Shouldn't that be `15`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to transform a document with XSLT then use a stylesheet with the identity transformation template plus templates for the changes you want to achieve:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="team[name = 'Sanha']/sum">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(../players/player/skill)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

I am not sure whether you only want to compute the sum for that particular team named `Sanha`, if you want to compute it for all teams simply change the match pattern to `<xsl:template match="team/sum">`.

Comment: What does `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>` mean and the `<xsl:template>` surrounded by? The second `<xsl:template>` is clear for me and than you for your answer.

Comment: See http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity or any book or tutorial on XSLT for the approach taken, as I said in my answer, it is the identity transformation template.

Comment: http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity is also a good introduction to the approach.